# Missing conversion warning using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, warnings

The code below generates a warning:

`warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'int64_t' to 'int', possible loss of data`

using CL 19 (with `-W3`).

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <climits>

int main() {  
  int64_t a = INT_MAX;
  int b = a+1;
}
```

However it seems as soon as I include anything Qt related like:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

the warning goes away. But I want those warnings to show for my own files. Is this Qt hiding its own warnings leaking into my source ? And can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of overly verbose warnings get disabled by `qglobal.h`, which is included (indirectly) by virtually any Qt header. Relevant code is [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h#n881).

To reenable them, **add `QT_CC_WARNINGS` to your defines** (in a qmake project, `DEFINES += QT_CC_WARNINGS`). I'm pretty sure this will trigger warnings from Qt headers...

Comment: Indeed, that works, i.e. I see my own warning among tons of warnings in the Qt headers. In my real project I am compiling with `/WX` though (warnings as errors) so I can't  simply enable that.

Comment: Not a Windows user, so I'm not sure what needs to be done to clean Qt headers from that point of view.

Comment: You could disable Qt's own logic, and write a couple of macros to push all those disable warnings and pop them. Then, use the macros around Qt's inclusion.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like wrapping the includes in `#pragma warning(push) ... #pragma warning(pop)` works. I also found a qt specific bug report regarding this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26877 . Nothing seem to have happened in the 4 years since it was reported though.

Comment: Hm, the warning push/pop did not work as I expected. Headers that included headers that did this wrapping still got the Qt warnings.